# Calling a custom function in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying out [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) and I simply can't get the x(d). Everything else works fine until I use x(d). I even tried copying and pasting the exact source code from [this page](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386).

The problem is with the use of x(d) since everything works if a constant is used instead of the x(d). What am I missing?

```
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <script src="https//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
                .range([0, 420]);

        d3.select(".chart")
                .selectAll("div")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("div")
                .style("width", function (d) {
                    return x(d) + "px";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d;
                });

    </script>
```

Comment: what is not working in this..everything is fine as expected. Here is a working fiddle...https://plnkr.co/edit/UxWI2MQ2wIiF6NDiAvgu?p=preview

Comment: it seems ok http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/dXBJyr

Comment: When I use the latest version v4, it is not working.

Comment: You should obviously read what has changed between v3 && v4
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale

Comment: `d3.scale.linear ↦ d3.scaleLinear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading this: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale

Try this:

```
        var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
                .range([0, 420]);

        d3.select(".chart")
                .selectAll("div")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("div")
                .style("width", function (d) {
                    return x(d) + "px";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d;
                });



    <div class="chart"></div>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
```

Comment: The source link needs https but the solution is correct. Too bad I didn't think to look into the version updates before.